# Why is the solution of $y''=\cos(x)/y$ increasing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying the equation:

> $$ y''=\frac {\cos(x)}y$$

, with `y(0)>>1` and `y'(0)=0`. I can't find an exact solution so I calculated it using Runge-Kutta. Intuitively I expect an oscillatory function where the average value remains constant, since y" is oscillatory. However, the solution I get is increasing. It looks roughly like

> $$y(x)= y_0+x+\cos(x)$$

Am I doing something wrong or is this the real behavior? And if so, can anyone try to find an explanation of why it would be increasing? I also found that it seems extremely sensitive to the initial value y'(0). If this is negative then the solution is decreasing (this is intuitively so), but I don't get why it is so sensitive, i.e. `y'(0)=-0.001` and `y(0)=10` will make the solution decreasing.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: $y$ is not monotonically increasing; [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y*y%27%27%3Dcos%28x%29%2C+y%27%280%29%3D0%2C+y%280%29%3D100) with $y(0)=100$.

Comment: Intuitively, one may expect the asymptotics $y(x)=ax+b$ for at least some domain in the space of possible initial conditions (it is consistent with the differential equation as its right side vanishes for large $y$). Also, intuitively, the initial conditions in your problem have all chances to belong to this domain (again because the right side is close to zero and solution can be approximated by a linear function). But it's not immediately clear to me how to transform this heuristic reasoning into a rigorous proof.

Comment: Is increasing if $y(0) = 0, y'(0) \gg 1$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we restrict to an interval on which $y > 0$, so we may write
$$  y'' y = \cos x  $$
then recognize $(y' y)' = y'' y + (y')^2$ and add $(y')^2$ to both sides, producing
$$  (y' y)' = \cos x + (y')^2  \text{.}  $$
Now let us look at the average behaviour over any one period of cosine.  \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} & \int_x^{x+2\pi} \; (y'(t) y(t))' \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left( y(x+2\pi)y'(x+2\pi) - y(x)y'(x) \right)  \text{,}  \\
\frac{1}{2\pi} & \int_x^{x+2\pi} \; \cos(t) + (y'(t))^2 \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( 0 + \int_x^{x+2\pi} \; (y'(t))^2 \,\mathrm{d}t \right)  \\
&\geq 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Putting these together, 
$$  y(x+2\pi)y'(x+2\pi) \geq y(x)y'(x)  \text{.}  $$
Your intuition tells you $y'$ is (approximately) oscillatory with period $2\pi$, giving $y(x+2\pi) \gtrsim y(x)$, so you expect $y$ oscillates with amplitude $1/y$ and slowly trends upwards.

This is what we see in the solution.  For instance, with $y(0) = 100$,
[image: solution plot]

Comment: His intuition did not *necessarily* tell him that $y$ is periodic -- only that it oscillates, and that's certain.

Answer (score 0):

From the initial conditions, it follows that $$0<y''(0)=\frac{1}{y(0)}< 1.$$ This means that $y'$ increases near $x=0,$ and since $y'(0)=0,$ it follows that $y'(x)>0$ for all $0<x<\epsilon,$ for some $\epsilon.$ Thus, $y$ must be an increasing function of $x$ in the interval $(0,\epsilon),$ and we probably can't say anything more definite than this based on just what we know.

Of course this tells us nothing about the behaviour of $y$ away from the origin -- it may indeed be increasing, but we cannot say. So one may want to say that you should trust your intuitive expectation of the behaviour of $y(x)$ more than what your approximation suggests.

However, one should point out that *there is **necessarily** no conflict between the expectation that $y$ changes concavity and the result of the approximation, which suggests monotony.* As is well known, both properties are compatible, for example in the function $g(x)=x+\sin x.$ I think where the confusion comes from is from how you interpreted what the equation tells you, immediately jumping to oscillation from mere variation in concavity -- but that doesn't follow. Indeed **the equation only tells you that $y$ varies in concavity; but that of itself does not mean that $y$ oscillates,** or repeats itself in some interval, which would necessarily imply non-monotony. As the example $g(x)$ above shows, a function need not repeat values (oscillate) yet it may change its concavity in any fashion (in the example it merely alternates it periodically, but this need not be the case in general). I hope this finally clears the air.

By the way yours is a good question. Kudos!

---

We can in fact say something more definite than what's here above, namely that your intuition that $y''$ changes sign is correct; what's not quite right is the deduction that therefore $y$ oscillates. Well, all we can deduce from the non-constancy of the sign of $y''$ is that $y$ alters its concavity, as explained above. Now how do we know that $y''$ cannot have constant sign?

Suppose to the contrary that $y$ has constant sign. Then either $y''>0$ throughout or it is negative, or it vanishes identically. This last case is easily dismissed since that would mean $\cos x=0$ for all $x\ge 0.$

So suppose $y''>0$ identically. Then it must be the case that $\cos x$ and $y$ have the same sign on the positive half-axis. Thus they must have the same roots as well, by continuity of $y.$ Hence, $y$ oscillates infinitely often as $x$ becomes large, since $\cos x$ oscillates for all $x.$ On the other hand we must have that $y'$ increases throughout the interval, so that $y$ must be convex. Thus, $y$ possesses a globally minimum value -- either at $x=0,$ or at some $x=x_m>0.$ In both cases, it follows that $y$ is monotonically increasing for sufficiently large $x$ (precisely for all $x$ greater than the minimum point). This contradicts the conclusion above that $y$ oscillates for *all* $x\ge 0.$ It follows that $y''$ cannot be positive for all $x\ge 0.$

Similarly, we conclude that $y''$ cannot be identically negative on the half-axis.

It follows that $y''$ changes sign as $x\to +\infty,$ which means that $y$ changes its concavity, from being down to up, etc. This however, as I've stressed above, does not mean that $y$ cannot be monotonic.

Indeed your approximations of the solution would seem to say that this is indeed what's the case.

Comment: Until $x=\pi/2$ I guess, when the sign of the cosine changes. Until that point, $y'' > 0$ and so $y'$ is increasing. Because $y'$ starts at $0$, it will be positive until then (and a bit later ofc).

Comment: It is not even **monotonic** increasing for quite small values of $y(0)$ such as 5. But it does seem to oscillate about a monotonically increasing value even for quite large values of $y(0)$ such as 100. But once you get above say 50, some care is needed on the precision etc.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Alas, we're not sure exactly for what neighborhood of the origin $y$ is positive, so we can't say definitely in what interval $y''>0$ too.

Comment: @almagest From the given conditions (and continuity, if you've forgotten!), it follows that it *must* be monotonic in some right-neighbourhood of the origin, no matter how small it is.

Comment: We know for certain $y$ is positive and increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$. By continuity it should still be increasing a bit past $\pi/2$ (but we don't know how far past).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I don't see anywhere in the given conditions where we can deduce that $y>0$ expect at the origin. Could you show me how you deduced this? All I can say for now is that the function is increasing in $(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon.$

Comment: $y''>0$ at $0$ and hence $y'$ is increasing at $0$. Because $y' = 0$ at $0$, $y'$ is hence positive near $0^+$, so $y$ is increasing near $0^+$. This remains true as long as $y'' > 0$, which is until the cosine changes signs.

Comment: @Allawonder If you mean that nothing on this page at the moment proves more than that $y$ is monotonic in some (small) interval about the origin I agree. But if you look at the numerical results for a range of initial $y(0)$ it is striking that $y$ oscillates about a monotonically increasing curve. I agree that proves nothing, but it is suggestive.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri You're still not getting the point that the sign of $y''$ depends on the sign of $y$ as well as it depends on that of the cosine. Hence your last sentence above is not true -- or at least not the latter part of it.

Comment: No, I can't. $y$ is positive throughout the interval considered. (Considering the given initial condition that $y(0) >> 1$ as in the statement)

Comment: @Fimpellizieri How do you know that $y>0$ in $[0,π/2]$ only from the equation and the given conditions?

Comment: It is $>0$ at $0$ and increasing in that range, like I said above.

Comment: @almagest Well, the plausibility of such suggestion depends on how accurate the approximations are.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri No, you don't know yet that it is increasing up to $π/2.$ You only know as explained in my answer above that it increases up to some $\epsilon >0.$

Comment: Suppose $y\leqslant 0$ for some $0<x<\pi/2$. Because $y(0) > 0$, we must have that $S = \{x \in [0,\pi/2]\,|\, y'(x) < 0\}$ is nonempty; let $s = \inf S$. Because $y''(0)>0$, $y'$ is increasing at $0$. Since $y'(0) = 0$, we must have $y'> 0$ at $(0,\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon > 0$ small enough. It follows that $s>0$.
Therefore, $y' > 0$ on $(0,s)$, so $y$ is increasing on $(0,s)$. It follows that $y > 0$ on $(0,s)$, so $y'' > 0$ on $(0,s)$ and hence $y'$ is increasing on $(0,s)$. But by definition of $s$ we would need to have $y'(s)\leqslant 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Precisely what does $y'(s)\le 0$ contradict?

Comment: $y'$ being increasing and positive on $(0,s)$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri No, it doesn't since obviously $s\notin (0,s).$

Comment: Positive numbers don't increase to $0$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I don't see what that means here. In any case I'd suggest this should stop here. The comments are already to long. In the large these things are irrelevant. See my edited post for what I think about what's happening to $y$ in the large.